# Number of ways to seat boys and girls in pairs

Tags: combinatorics

An elementary school teacher wants to seat the pupils, 12 boys and 12 girls,in such a way that they sit in pairs, a boy and a girl. How many ways are there to do that? The answer is 12!. Could you explain how we obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

Take the first boy. There are 12 girls to pair him up with.  Once we have picked on of those, move on to the second boy. Since there are 11 girls left to pair up with the second boy, there are now 11 possible ways to pair up the second boy.  Etc.  So you get $12*11*10*...*1 = 12!$ possibilities to do all pairing up.